# how to store reference of objects in a list in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a class Country and another class CountryBO.
From main class, I am instantanieting CountryBO, and on the object of CountryBO, I am calling a method defined in 
CoountryBO class called as createCountry.
In this method I am instantanieting object of Country class and setting some variables, also returning the reference of newly created object.

```
    public Country createCountry(String data)
    {
        string [] countryDetail = data.Split(',');
        Country myCountry = new Country();
        myCountry._countryCode=countryDetail[2];
        myCountry._isdCode=countryDetail[1];
        myCountry._name=countryDetail[0];
        return myCountry;  
    }
```

Now in the calling Main class, I want to create a list of all the objects of Country class hat were created.
But I am not able to do it.

```
CountryBO myCountryBO = new CountryBO();
    Country[] countryList = new Country[];
    countryList = myCountryBO.createCountry(countryDetails);
    countryCount +=1;
```

Comment: Can you post definition of both classes? Also what error you encounter?

Comment: Use `List<Country>` instead, then you can use `list.Add(myCountryBO.createCountry)`. Arrays are not as feature rich as generic lists.

Comment: The problem is ill-defined, is it possible countryCount needs to be static? I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a `List<Country>` and not a `Country[]`.

Try this:

```
Country[] countryList = new List<Country>();
CountryBO myCountryBO = new CountryBO();
countryList.Add(myCountryBO.createCountry(countryDetails));
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, but it did not work.

```
Country[] countryList = new List<Country>();
CountryBO myCountryBO = new CountryBO();
countryList.Add(myCountryBO.createCountry(countryDetails));
```

In place, what I did was captured he return objects reference in a list, and then converted hat to array using ToArray method on list class.

```
List<Country> countryList_temp = new List<Country>();
countryList_temp.Add(myCountryBO.createCountry(countryDetails));
Country[] countryList = countryList_temp.ToArray();
```